# SQL Server 2014 String Search for Categorization: Complex CASE WHEN (rules) for Multiple Search Strings

Tags: case, sql-server-2014, data-cleaning, substring

I am working with a legacy data entry system that didn't use controlled inputs. Everything is stored in a varchar(max) field, and unfortunately, contains many variants in how things are said.

If I want to know when something is calibrated, I can't just say "where t.col like '%cal%'

It would work in cases like "CAL, CAL., Calib. Calibrate, calibrate, Calibration, calibration, Cal'd..." but not for a variant that was misspelled.

Also, the person may be saying "NO cal reqd, didn't cal., "

The text may "infer" that the action took place. "Calibration" might be written as "Adjusted to baseline, Adjusted per procedure."

As you can see by one case, there literally thousands of potential "rules."

It took me about 2 weeks to work with about 30K records and intelligently parse them into about 30 (0,1 / true/false) categories that the data fell into.

I want to know if anyone can point me to helpful query construct using T-SQL to replace manual processing.

Comment: There is no magic button you can use to get structured data out of unstructured text.

Comment: @JNK, there might be queries with rules that can be tweaked for this project. If I don't have to write the entire thing from scratch, it would be helpful. Clearly this is complicated. I get that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following written by Dejan Sarka, Microsoft MVP: **Indexing, Querying and Analyzing Text with SQL Server 2012-2014**: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/description/indexing-querying-analyzing-text-with-sqlserver-2012-2014

The page says "It is hard to imagine searching for something on the Web without modern search engines like Bing or Google. However, most contemporary applications still limit users to exact searches only. For end users, even the standard SQL LIKE operator is not powerful enough for approximate searches. In addition, many documents are stored in modern databases; end users would probably like to get powerful search inside document contents as well. Text mining is also becoming more and more popular. Everybody would like to understand data from blogs, Web sites, and social media. Microsoft SQL Server in versions 2012 and 2014 enhances full-text search support that was substantially available in previous editions. Semantic Search, a new component in Full-Text Search, can help you understand the meaning of documents. Finally, the Term Extraction and Term Lookup components from SQL Server Integration Services also helps ."

This is along the lines of what I am seeking. Thx! -S